# parse dictionary with different keys and values

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```
var mapNames: [String: [String]] = 
    [
          "A": ["A1", "A2"],
          "B": ["B1"],
          "C": ["C1", "C2", "C3"]
    ]
```

Now I have a 1st View controller's tableview's func:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

 //I want to print "A", "B", "C" here.

}
```

In my 2nd View Controller's tableview' func:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

  //If user taps on "A" in the 1st VC, show here cells with "A1", "A2"

}
```

Can someone help with how can i parse my dictionary to get list of keys first and then for each key, get list of corresponding values ?

Thanks.

Comment: Learn from the source: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID113

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed by Eric, you should read the documentation first. To get key - value of a dictionary, you need to do  this:

```
for (key, value) in mapNames {
   print(key)
   print(mapNames[key])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For solving of the problem try to split `Dictionary` to `Array`.

Example :

```
var mapNames: [String: [String]] =
[
    "A": ["A1", "A2"],
    "B": ["B1"],
    "C": ["C1", "C2", "C3"]
]

var mapNamesKeys  = mapNames.keys

var mapNamesValues  = mapNames.values
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all the keys from the dictionary, use

```
let keys = mapNames.keys
//keys is the array you need on 1st view controller
```

Now to get the array corresponding to each `key`, use

```
for key in keys
{
    let value = mapNames[key]
    //value is the array you need on 2nd view controller corresponding to the selected key
}
```